# finding and returning names and counts of duplicate values in Python list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of values that denote the number of times a piece of regex matches in a string. From this, I want to find the numbers that appear more than once, and their count.  For example, for `[2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3]` I want `{2:4,3:2}` as output if it's in a dict or `[[2,4],[3,2]]` if it's in a list of lists. I'm looking for the fastest, most concise way to do this.  Right now, I do it via the following code, but think it's way to verbose to be optimal.

```
numWinners=[2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1]
tieCount={x:numWinners.count(x) for x in numWinners}
ties=dict()
for key, value in tieCount.items():
    if value>1:
        ties[key]=value

print ties
{2: 4, 3: 2}
```

A list or dict output isn't really an issue for me - again, whatever is fastest and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to create a histogram:

```
>>> ns=[2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3]
>>> {x: ns.count(x) for x in set(ns) if ns.count(x) > 1}
{2: 4, 3: 2}
```

Comment: I like your option as it's more concise. Is it faster than `collections.Counter`?

Comment: I don't know, but I thought it was an idiom worth sharing.  I don't like the double call to ns.count though.

Comment: This is the least efficient option given; it loops through the input *two times per unique element* plus once over all elements, once over unique elements. Cost `O(N+M^3)`. The `Counter` solution costs `O(N+M)`.

Comment: `dict(filter(lambda t: t[1]>1, ((x, ns.count(x)) for x in set(ns))))`

Comment: Or `{x: c for x in set(ns) for c in [ns.count()] if c > 1}`

Answer (score 5):

I'd combine [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with a dictionary comprehension to select the duplicates:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> numWinners = [2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3]
>>> counts = Counter(numWinners)
>>> {k: v for k,v in counts.items() if v > 1}
{2: 4, 3: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `collections.defaultdict`

```
import collections
ties = collections.defaultdict(lambda:0)
for num in numWinners:
     ties[num] = ties[num]+1


 for key,value in ties.iteritems():
     print key, value
```